# Need IP Tables rules to block DoS/DDoS attacks (IP Spoofing and SYN flood attack)

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a network switch where I am trying to install the IP Tables rules to prevent different types of DOS/DDOS attacks. Below is the network layout.

```
Laptop-1 ------- router ---- Network switch ---- customer devices
                   |
Laptop-2 -----------
```

I am trying to attack the switch from Laptop-1 and the switch is going into hung state.

Below are the DoS/DDoS attacks I am trying to prevent.

```
IP spoofing
    Attack command: hping3 -a 192.168.1.1 -S -p 80 --flood 192.168.22.140
    Result: System hangs
    
SYN flood - half handshake
    Attack command: hping3 -V -c 1000 -d 10 -S -p 80 --flood 192.168.22.140
    Result: System hangs
    
ICMP flood
    Attack command: hping3 -1 --flood -a 192.168.22.140 192.168.22.140
    Attack command: hping3 -1 --flood -a 192.168.22.15 192.168.22.140
    Result: System hangs
```

For ICMP flood, I have already a rule in place, but I need help in finding the desired rule for IP Spoofing and SYN flood attack. The rule should be installed in such a manner that it should block attacker from any subnet.

I am using following iptables version: `iptables-1.8.5 (legacy build)`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Variables
IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"
RLIMIT="-m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 10"
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Drop invalid packets 
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Drop TCP packets that are new and are not SYN 
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Drop SYN packets with suspicious MSS value
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Block packets with bogus TCP flags
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Limit TCP connections per source IP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Protection against SYN FLOOD
$IPTABLES -N SYN_FLOOD
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j SYN_FLOOD
$IPTABLES -A SYN_FLOOD $RLIMIT -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -A SYN_FLOOD -j DROP
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Save the rules
/sbin/iptables-save
```

Comment: There are many redundant and duplicate rules in the "bogus TCP flags" list. Dups are 2&4 and also 6&8; #10 is superseded by any of #2-#5; #11 is superseded by #1; #12 & #13 is superseded by #6; #14 is superseded by #3. You could cut that list in half and save some CPU cycles.